# How can I recover contact information from a stolen phone?

Tags: contacts, anti-theft

My phone got stolen yesterday. The problem is that all phone numbers are in it, and I don't know any numbers now.

I tried many different solutions to get my contacts to PC.

1. Google

   I went into my Gmail account, and on the left side of the screen selected *Contacts > My Contacts*, but none of my phone contact's names or numbers are there. Only the e-mail contacts are there with the e-mail addresses.
2. Bluestacks

   I installed Bluestacks on my PC, managed to login with my Google account, but the contacts are not there, and most of the apps require SMS verification.

Is there any way that I recover the contact information from my phone?

Answer (score 1):

IT depends, if you were using the built-in Contacts, then the contacts are stored on the phone. There are apps. that allow you to remote control your phone via Internet or SMS, but, if you didn't install any of these (like Lookout, etc.), then your contacts cannot be retrieved.